# Pan gesture (hold/drag) zoom on camera like Snapchat

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, zooming, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to replicate Snapchat camera's zoom feature where once you have started recording you can drag your finger up or down and it will zoom in or out accordingly. I have been successful with zooming on pinch but have been stuck on zooming with the `PanGestureRecognizer`.

Here is the code I've tried the problem is that I do not know how to replace the `sender.scale` that I use for pinch gesture recognizer zooming. I'm using AVFoundation. Basically, I'm asking how I can do the hold zoom (one finger drag) like in TikTok or Snapchat properly.

```
let minimumZoom: CGFloat = 1.0
let maximumZoom: CGFloat = 15.0
var lastZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
var latestDirection: Int = 0

@objc func panGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let velocity = sender.velocity(in: doubleTapSwitchCamButton)
    var currentDirection: Int = 0

    if velocity.y > 0 || velocity.y < 0 {

                let originalCapSession = captureSession
                var devitce : AVCaptureDevice!

                let videoDeviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDuoCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
                let devices = videoDeviceDiscoverySession.devices
                devitce = devices.first!

                guard let device = devitce else { return }

                    // Return zoom value between the minimum and maximum zoom values
                    func minMaxZoom(_ factor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
                        return min(min(max(factor, minimumZoom), maximumZoom), device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor)
                        }

                        func update(scale factor: CGFloat) {
                            do {

                                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                                defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }
                                device.videoZoomFactor = factor
                            } catch {
                                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }

//These 2 lines below are the problematic ones, pinch zoom uses this one below, and the newScaleFactor below that is a testing one that did not work.
                let newScaleFactor = minMaxZoom(sender.scale * lastZoomFactor)
                       //let newScaleFactor = CGFloat(exactly: number + lastZoomFactor)


                    switch sender.state {

                    case .began: fallthrough                
                    case .changed: update(scale: newScaleFactor!)                
                    case .ended:
                        lastZoomFactor = minMaxZoom(newScaleFactor!)
                        update(scale: lastZoomFactor)

                    default: break
                    }

        } else {

        }

        latestDirection = currentDirection

    }
```

Comment: I don't think UIPanGesutureRecognizer has a scale. Instead I think you should determine the max zoom factor, then create incremental zoom levels (say 5 for example), when a PanGesuture is recognized just increase or decrease the zoom factor to one of the pre-determined levels. If you're willing to share your code on github I can show you.

Comment: Well, I've tried that before; I'll post the code that I tried shortly, but I incremented it by +1 zoom, but it does not work as desired.

Comment: @DoesData the answer below solved it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the gesture recogniser's translation property, to calculate the displacement in points, and normalise this displacement as a zoom factor.

Fitting this into your code, you could try:

```
 ... somewhere in your view setup code, i.e. viewDidLoad.... 
     let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture))
     button.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

 private var initialZoom: CGFloat = 1.0
 @objc func panGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    // note that 'view' here is the overall video preview
    let velocity = sender.velocity(in: view)

    if velocity.y > 0 || velocity.y < 0 {

       let originalCapSession = captureSession
       var devitce : AVCaptureDevice!

       let videoDeviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDuoCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
       let devices = videoDeviceDiscoverySession.devices
       devitce = devices.first!

       guard let device = devitce else { return }

        let minimumZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
        let maximumZoomFactor: CGFloat = min(device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor, 10.0) // artificially set a max useable zoom of 10x

        // clamp a zoom factor between minimumZoom and maximumZoom
        func clampZoomFactor(_ factor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            return min(max(factor, minimumZoomFactor), maximumZoomFactor)
        }

        func update(scale factor: CGFloat) {
            do {

                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }
                device.videoZoomFactor = factor
            } catch {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        switch sender.state {

        case .began:
            initialZoom = device.videoZoomFactor
            startRecording() /// call to start recording your video

        case .changed:

            // distance in points for the full zoom range (e.g. min to max), could be view.frame.height
            let fullRangeDistancePoints: CGFloat = 300.0

            // extract current distance travelled, from gesture start
            let currentYTranslation: CGFloat = sender.translation(in: view).y

            // calculate a normalized zoom factor between [-1,1], where up is positive (ie zooming in)
            let normalizedZoomFactor = -1 * max(-1,min(1,currentYTranslation / fullRangeDistancePoints))

            // calculate effective zoom scale to use
            let newZoomFactor = clampZoomFactor(initialZoom + normalizedZoomFactor * (maximumZoomFactor - minimumZoomFactor))

            // update device's zoom factor'
            update(scale: newZoomFactor)

        case .ended, .cancelled:
            stopRecording() /// call to start recording your video
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well! Ill award the bounty once I further test it momentarily.

Comment: yes it works well, but how can I make it so that once youve already tapped on a button you can move up with the same finger and zoom. Like snapchat where you hold the button and can zoom up with that same finger your holding the cam button with.

Comment: I see... you could handle the start / stop recording in the .began and .ended events... Make sure to attach the gesture recogniser to your button, but use the super view to calculate the translation. See my edited answer

Comment: Ok ill check the code and respond later... Thanks for the help till now.